# Can we give a badge to heroes?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badge-request

I'd like to see a badge for "heroes" and a hero nomination system. [Peter Bailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8815/peter-bailey) inspired this with all his help on obscure JavaScript questions that no one else helped answer (like [cross frame event handling in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059574/javascript-event-not-being-set-correctly-in-closure-when-called-cross-frame/1059902#1059902)).  **The idea doesn't need to be a badge**, but it'd be nice to be able to give more personal feedback than an upvote and an accepted answer.

Comment: Isn't the person who answered your question almost always a 'hero'?

Comment: Yeah, but sometimes the solution is so elusive that the answerer deserves a beer or a badge or something

Comment: Now that I've said it, I think it should be called the "Owed-A-Beer" badge. Or "hero badge" is ok, too, I guess

Comment: I definitely owe him a beer!

Comment: I'm tempted to vote to close this as a duplicate of [Please add a means of converting reputation to actual beer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70088/please-add-means-of-converting-reputation-to-actual-beer).

Comment: @Pop, that one is newer than this one, so it'd have to be the other way around.

Comment: @Juan it was a joke...

Comment: @Pop, mine wasn't

Answer (score 10):

Badges are all awarded programatically - this doesn't sound like something StackOverflow could determine.

If you want to personally thank someone, leave them a comment!

Comment: which is why I declined this request...

Answer (score 6):

> it'd be nice to be able to give more personal feedback than an upvote and an accepted answer.

The bounty system allows one to essentially "tip" a user.  Set up the bounty on the question, wait until you can assign the bounty, then click the bounty button next to the answer.

The user gets a bounty of reputation as a tip, and the answer is highlighted with the bounty award next to it in blue.

I hesitate to add a hero badge of any sort, because we already get enough complaints about people not accepting answers, or people accepting the wrong answers.  I worry that people might think they deserve a hero award and start campaigning for it.

Nevertheless, if a hero award is established, please review my voluminous works and consider voting me into the hero hall of fame.

Answer (score 2):

Thinking of the number of times I've wanted to give someone more than +1 and the number of similar comments abounding on SO, this seems like a nice compromise on this subject would be to actually be able to do so.

You could limit such supervotes by time period, or let them cost rep - I'd happily (but perhaps not frequently) offer some of my rep to somebody for writing something particularly awesome.

Comment: Interesting idea. Would this extra up-vote earn the same rep?

Comment: Yeah I think it would, but that's just an implementation detail to me

Comment: The [bounty system was modified](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/) about a year after this question was first asked to more or less allow what you're suggesting.

Answer (score 2):

You can already reward the answer with both an up-vote and acceptance which will give them 25 rep.

If you don't think this enough then a comment on the answer is a good way of acknowledging the "debt".