# I want to applaud someone for editing my question or comment, how do I do that?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Let me reward a good edit on my question/answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36574/let-me-reward-a-good-edit-on-my-question-answer)
>   [Etiquette for thanking an editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11226/etiquette-for-thanking-an-editor)

Someone is always fixing my questions to correct the spelling, but how does one give them credit for it? Is there a way to accept the edit and give them some reputation? They did took time and thought to edit the question - should they not be rewarded for their diligent work?

If there is no current way to give reputation for a edit or correction, shouldn't there be one?

Comment: The best award is to learn from it!

Comment: No this refers to editing a post or comment for grammatical errors where the other is for better ways to show an edit done to question or comment that changes or adds information. @Arjan

Comment: Then "fixing [...] and correcting the spelling" should probably read "fixing [...] to correct the spelling"... Still then: not much difference, I'd say. Also, the "linked" section in that question shows quite a few other duplicates.

Comment: BTW- I agree about the best award is to learn from it, but still many people take lots of time to modify the questions and get unnoticed. I see questions filled with typos that doesn't get an answer until someone edits the question. At the very least a user who made a change to a question that finds an answer after wards should get some points... Don't you think so? Plus there is no way to reward them now?

Comment: @justin From the linked question - "Usual expedient: go to their profile, find a deserving question or answer of theirs and vote for it. Extra fun when you can bump them into a badge."

Comment: I still think [bratwurst](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11226/etiquette-for-thanking-an-editor/11232#11232) is the way to go...

Comment: You could skip the reputation step and convert your gratitude [directly into tangible benefits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70088/please-add-means-of-converting-reputation-to-actual-beer)....

Comment: How sad that my question got closed. But I'm glad to know many people out there do want to thank the editors out there.