# Using SO to complete whole project by posting multiple questions regarding a task

Tags: discussion

I have come across many novice users who tend to post minimum of 5-10 questions each day to accomplish a particular task in their project. The questions they ask are of little or no use for future users. Those questions are too project-centric. What to do with these kind of users or questions? How do I flag those questions as a whole? These are links to profiles of two such users [user 1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2807197/user2807197) 
[user2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2818444/constantin-jacob)

**Update:**

As far as the OP asks clear questions (understandable, demonstrating his/her efforts so far (which is obviously the result of answers provided by other users in SO in response to OP's previous questions regarding the same task)), is it acceptable in SO that the OP completes his/her homework/project using SO, with minimal programming knowledge, as witnessed in case of user1 and user2 (links I have provided)?

Comment: `Those questions are too project-centric` And is it really a problem? It could be worse if you try to limit user questions, they will still be able to create multiple accounts.

Comment: how exactly you define `too project-centric` ?

Comment: Confined to a single project.

Comment: As you can see in case of user1 in one question the problem was with his `delete FROM touch where xcoor = '%f','%f'` wrong sql statement and in other question of same user problem was with `SELECT xcoor FROM touch where xcoor = '%f','%f'`.How much are these 2 questions useful for future users?

Comment: If they are bad questions, handle them like you would any other bad question. That it's all related to one user's project doesn't really matter.

Comment: I miss the close as `Too localized` option is a lot of such cases.

Comment: @Bart what would be the appropriate flag for such kind of questions?

Comment: It depends on what problem (if any) the individual question has. Eg. if the question is asking for code, but does not include what the expected behavior is, how the OP tried to solve the problem or how it failed, you should close the question as off topic - must demonstrate minimal understanding.

Comment: Related: [Should SO get the proceeds from iPhone apps coded by answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94675)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think every question has to be looked as a completely separate question (at least if it doesn't contain any links to other questions).

If a question is **complete and good**, it should be left to be answered. It doesn't matter that it is a part of the series as long as it's complete, i.e. understanding it doesn't depend on reading other questions.

If a question doesn't meet the **normal criteria** of good questions, it should be dealt with appropriately by flagging it or closing.

Comment: So there is no problem in completing whole project/homework using SO with minimal/No programming knowledge until OP asks valid questions?

Comment: Basically yes if the questions are good. But I find it hard to believe that someone who has only minimal knowledge of the area can ask the whole series of good questions.

Comment: @PratyushaTerli "lack of minimal understanding" is one of the valid close reasons, so no, it's not OK, but it has nothing to do with the fact it's a part of some project.

Comment: @mMolot thank you for specifying that flag. That was the problem I did not know what flag should be used to flag such questions. It is really annoying to see users with minimum programming knowledge (and putting no efforts to learn) asking so many questions on a single topic.

Comment: @PratyushaTerli Its not a "flag for moderator attention" flag, but rather "put this in the close vote review queue".  The minimal understanding is one of the reasons that close voters are able to select when closing a question.